# Nature of behaviour shown by tracks of Bike and relation of tracks with length of frame of bike?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life

If a bike wheels are moving along two paths such that front wheel traces a sinx curve , how to show that back wheel will also transverse a sinusoidal curve with lesser/greater amplitude than the front one , and if the curves graph is given can we able to find the length of the frame between the wheels ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be of help to read the paper by Apostol and Mnatsakanian "The method of sweeping tangents" which deals with a similar question.

Comment: You may refer to that paper for writing a explanation as i think writing it here will help more people than seeing it from a research paper for elaborative answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).